# Android Studio, perda do arquivo .jks

Tags: android, android-studio

Perdi o arquivo .jks da aplicação e agora não consigo mais atualizar o app na play store. O que eu posso fazer nesse caso?

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente você não poderá mais atualizar o aplicativo. Sugiro da próxima vez colocar a keystore em algum controle de versão.

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Fonte: [Google Play](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Resposta atualizada: você pode entrar em contato com o suporte do Google para resolver isso.

Veja "[Redefinir uma chave de upload privada perdida ou comprometida](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#reset_upload_key)":

> Se você perder sua chave de upload privada ou ela for comprometida,
>   crie uma nova e entre em contato com a equipe de suporte do Google
>   Play para [fazer a redefinição](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#reset).
>
> **Observação:** a redefinição da chave de upload não afetará a chave de
>   assinatura do app usada pelo Google Play para assinar novamente os
>   APKs antes de enviar o conteúdo aos usuários.

O processo resume-se a:

1. Criar uma nova chave (veja [aqui](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#create))
2. O dono da conta deve entrar em contato com o Google através de um formulário ([aqui](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs)), anexando o arquivo `.pem` gerado.
3. Aguardar o retorno da equipe de suporte via e-mail.